# Open Different page in different countries?

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I have a contact us link in my main menu. What I want to do is that I have two different contact us pages. I want to open contact us 1 page in England and contact us 2 page in rest of the world while using the same "Contact us" link. My site is wordpress. Any suggestion and any solution. Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use some plugin for supporting multiple languages. It's not so trivial to achieve on your own. The one I used before is WPML:

https://wpml.org/

It has nice documentation.

But probably there are some others too. Find the one that suits you most.

Comment: Thankyou MilanG..
Well I am not looking to translate the page in different countries... I am different contact details for england and different for rest of the world. That's what I want. to open different pages in different areas of the world

Comment: You want to have different page content depending on visitors country, right?

Comment: Exectly Thats what I am looking for

Answer (score 0):

There are couple of plugins out there to show the content based on the user's geolocation. There's one called [GeoTargeting](https://geotargetingwp.com/). With this, you can choose which page/post to show in which country.

Comment: [Link only answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers/8259#8259) are considered very low quality and [can get deleted](https://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers), please put the important parts from the linked resource into the answer body.